# Form Slide Transition Not Smooth

Tags: ios, codenameone

I used to test my apps using an iPhone 5S - now I switched to a iPhone SE.

Now I am asking myself why the default form slide transitions still stutter on such a fast device - the animation should always appear smooth if the calculated locations are correct relative to the timeline.

Looking into CommonTransitions I saw that there is a CommonTransitions.TYPE_FAST_SLIDE and wondered if this was the key to smooth transitions, is it?

In Theme Constants in the Codename One Designer under FormTransitionOut however there is no option fastSlide - why is that?

Comment: Fast slide is actually slower on modern devices especially iOS. Open the performance monitor and check the form to which you are sliding, see if there are any red flags on that form.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered the same, although I have only a cheap device to test on.

This may only add fuel to the fire, but have you tried `Display.setFramerate(int rate)`.  The docs say the default is an (attempted) rate of 10 (redraws per second).

Maybe it would look smoother with 20?

Comment: The current default is actually 60 so that's outdated, I would suggest not touching that flag...